# Two LTE routers have very different speeds

Tags: networking, router

I have two different LTE-Routers for my internet and telphone connection and they get rapidly different speeds. What could be the cause of this?

I wasn't sure if this should be on stackoverflow, but I didn't find a more suitable forum on stackexchange...

Quick explanation of the situation:
I currently don't have access to any sort of cable internet connection. Therefore I got LTE from Vodafone quite some years ago, when they were the only ISP having any LTE coverage here at all. However with the old system I got telephone, but only 25GB/Month of internet. So A few years ago I got a Gigacube from Vodafone in addition to that, because the Gigacube doesn't offer any telephone at all, but 200GB/Month for internet. I do need the telephone for a small business, so I can't get rid of that.

Now the problem:
I recently found out that when connected to the wifi of the telephone router (EasyBox 904 LTE) will get me speeds of up to 5-6Mbit/s Download, as long as the 25GB arent used up yet. When I am connected to the wifi of the Gigacube router (Huawei B528s-23a) I get a maximum of just about 2Mbit/s Download.
Both tested with only a single device on the network and the same device in both tests. Also the same page and same test server used for both tests.
Both routers are basically next to each other, but the EasyBox has an external LTE antenna connected to it, because otherwise it would basically have no connection at all (this way it has about half of the bars of reception). The B528 does not have an external antenna connected, but gets 2-3 of its 4 bars of reception.
I also checked which LTE band their using and they both use the 800MHz band (I'm in Germany).

Checking the settings of both routers, I could only find one other difference that might be important: They use different APNs. The EasyBox uses fixed.data.vodafone.de and the B528 uses home.vodafone.de .

My question is, why do I get so radically different speeds with the two routers and is there any way I could get the higher speed with the other router?

I am not interested in buying a new/different router or changing anything with the plans, because I will get fibre to the home within a year. I am just trying to get the best internet connection from the current setup...

Comment: The fact that they both do LTE in the 800MHz band does not imply that they both support every possible speed enhancing option of LTE. Can you get detailed specs of both LTE chipsets?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no way of getting any info about the actual chipsets. I tried searching the internet, but I could only figure out potentially what the chipsets might be called, but couldnt find any datasheets or anything on them.